# Magento 2.3.5: How to get csv from the WEB directory of Module?

Tags: php, custom, controllers, html, magento2.3.5-p1

I want to get csv file from web folder of custom module in magento 2 so how can i do this.
please help me.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to get it. Just matter is that in which file you want to get.

If you want to get it in phtml file then

```
$block->getViewFileUrl('VendorName_ModuleName::csvdirectory/file.csv');
```

From Block you may get via

```
$this->getViewFileUrl('VendorName_ModuleName::csvdirectory/file.csv');
```

Comment: Thaks but i want to get file from web directory from  module in magento 2

Comment: yes you can inject your block and get it ...